# fnDraw to redraw the datatable populated from DB

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

I use fnDraw to redraw the table. Look at the code below. This thread is similar to my previous one, but this provides an extended solution. The idea is to first call 'estimate.php' that updates DB and then reload the table that is populated from DB. The problem is that I can successfully call 'estimate.php', however the 'success' part of ajax is not performed well and the datatable stays unchanged.

```
<div id="refresh">
    <button id="refresh-table">Refresh</button>
    <br>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
         $(document).ready(function(){
              $('#newspaper-b').dataTable({
              "sPaginationType":"full_numbers",
              "aaSorting":[[5, "asc"]],
              "bJQueryUI":true
              });

              $("#refresh-table").button().click(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "callpage.php?page=estimate.php",
                        success: function(html) {
                            var table=$("#newspaper-b").dataTable();
                            table.fnReloadAjax();
                            table.fnDraw();
                        }
                    }); 
              });

     });
</script>
```

Comment: Is your table ajax or static?  If it is ajax, why are you not putting those values in the dataTable initial call?  If it is static, why do you need a refresh button?

Comment: I use jQuery datatable populated from DB. So, if DB is changed,I need to see new data in the table, no?

Comment: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html -- This is what you need to do.  You are not doing it if you want server-side processing.